# If I want to limit the bandwidth of this BJT to 10 kHz, what resistance should I consider when need to calculate the value of capacitor Cf?

Tags: analog, bjt, small-signal

[image: BJT circuit]
My wish is to get the capacitance value by calculating R when I use the hybrid-pi model, so use the formula Cf = 1 / (2 * pi * f * R).
I would like to ask if the R value needed to use in the above formula is R = Rb || Rc which is the capacitor “sees” or also need to consider using the Rpi and Ro value in the model?
[image]

Comment: Why not use a simulator? They are free, accurate (more accurate than hand calculations) and, it's a skill that you need to acquire if you are serious about EE.